# Lambda expression: Second row column data is coming as NULL if first row column is null when retrieve as list

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have the example data.

| Name | address | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tony | Singapore |  |
| Tony |  | xxx@gmail.com |

List E = _ctx.EMP.Where(x => x.name== 'Tony').ToList();

I am getting below result when retrieve below data format from above code.

| Name | address | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tony | Singapore |  |
| Tony | Singapore |  |

So in my list ,  Email column is coming as empty in both rows.
Can anyone help ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have my doubts that what you're claiming is happening is actually happening. The little code you posted wouldn't even compile, so it can't be your real code, and you haven't shown us how you're using the data, so we don't know whether the issue is the list or how you're reading it. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. You also need to do some thorough testing, like getting all records into a list first and viewing it, plus doing the filter locally to see what happens. If that works correctly but the database query doesn't then something is broken.

Comment: Hi All , I have fixed by adding my primary key id into the modal. Thanks all.

Comment: You should either add and accept an answer or delete the question. Don't leave resolved questions without answers.